# Ubuntu 12.04 server cannot access anything outside

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, ubuntu-12.04, ifconfig

My Ubuntu 12.04 server was working fine a few days ago. But today I couldn't access anything outside. And i cannot ssh to my server neither. I am directly plugged into the console through my vps provider.

I can ping myself, but not resolve any addresses outside.

I only know of ifconfig to display the network adapters and ping addresses. But I'm not sure what I need to do to trouble shoot this issue.

Oh I had to disable iptables in order for me to ping localhost, otherwise it wouldn't work. I'm not sure what happened as I didn't change any settings to iptables.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't changed anything? Try to ping your default gateway you can find out the IP with route -n

Comment: Post output of `route -n`

Comment: thanks for the help. I actually found the issue. it was due to my VPS provider. I knew i didn't change anything and nothing should be broken. I had to click on the rebuild network button on the vps page. -_-

Answer (score 1):

I was certain I didn't do anything to cause this issue, but it was my VPS provider after all. I just needed to click on the *rebuild network* button to get it working again.

[image]